# Git repository recovery

Tags: git, repository, move, remote-server

Our server is down/broken I copied the repo.git directory to my local computer and installed git on a new Ubuntu machine. Is there some way I can take these files and copy/paste them into the new server and have it running correctly as a new git remote repository?

I am trying to find a way to do it with just the files as the old git server is totally un-reachable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you did not use some special repo management software, you can just copy the files over. check that the file ownerships are set to the user you use. if the new server is reachable via another domain or you changed the username or the location of the git repo on the server you may need to update the remote(s) in `.git/config`.